# Create Task in outlook with SMTP Client

Tags: c#, email, outlook, smtp, smtpclient

I want to send e-mail task from outlook with smtp client.  I have already smtp client but I don't know how can I correlate smtp host and my code.

Here is my code:

```
string startWord = "#JSONTASK#";
 body = body.Substring(startWord.Length, body.Length - startWord.Length);
 dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(body);
 Dictionary<string, string> jsonElement = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 foreach (var item in json)
 {
     jsonElement.Add(item.Name.ToString(), item.First.ToString());
 }"password");
 Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
 if (outlookApp == null)
 {
     outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
 }
 Outlook.TaskItem oTask = outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olTaskItem);
 oTask.Subject = jsonElement["Subject"];
 oTask.DueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(jsonElement["DueDate"]);
 oTask.StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(jsonElement["StartDate"]);
 oTask.ReminderSet = Convert.ToBoolean(jsonElement["ReminderSet"]);
 oTask.ReminderTime = Convert.ToDateTime(jsonElement["ReminderTime"]);
 oTask.Body = jsonElement["Body"];
 oTask.SchedulePlusPriority = jsonElement["SchedulePlusPriority"];
 oTask.Status = Outlook.OlTaskStatus.olTaskInProgress;
 oTask.Save();
 Outlook.Recipients oReceipients = oTask.Recipients;
 Outlook.Recipient oReceipient;
 oReceipient = jsonElement["ToMail"];
 oReceipient.Type = 1;
 oReceipients.ResolveAll();
 oTask.Assign();
 ((Outlook._TaskItem)oTask).Send();
```

Comment: Your code creates a new task, assigns it, and sends it out. Why do you need to send a task with a `SMTPClient` instead?

Comment: I have to use ``SMTPClient`` because every mails goes with ``SMTPHost`` in my project.

Comment: well, you could export the task created in Outlook and then use it as a base for using in the SMTPClient-based code.

Comment: How can I do that? Could you give an example or reference?